# CakeDC Users Plugin

Tags: plugins, admin, prefix, cakedc

I have installed the CakeDC Users Plugin but I like to use it also in the Admin-backend of my application.
Can someone point me out how to start with this? Is this Plugin already complete and do I only need to duplicate the Controllers and Templates into an Admin-folder? Or is this just the registration, login, etc... for the users and do I need to bake all backend stuff from scratch?
I'm missing some info on this in the docs.
Grateful for any step by step help to put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case matches with the documentation here [Github CakeDC Documentation](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md#extending-the-controller) you might want to create a new controller inside your admin folder, and then use the traits you need to attach the features required.

You can re-use plugin templates too but usually you'll be rewriting the templates to match your site UI. If you still want to reuse plugin templates you can change your view path in the admin controller's beforeRender callback.

The plugin is complete and it's being used in several live applications now.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: I'm looking for something like the Alaxos ACL Plugin (https://github.com/oldskool/Acl) for CakePHP 3.x with all necessary views to manage acos, aros and acos_aros. Is that available? I have installed cakephp/acl and cakedc/users plugins and I read everywhere these two plugins are completely functional but I can't find any views to really manage the group and user permissions. Do I need to create them all by myself? Or am I missing something here?